# I need infinite onclick and transitions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, gallery, css-transitions

I am trying to make a photo gallery and I have 2 problems...

1. In my javascript "onclick" I can click only 1 time, I need to be able to click any number of times
2. My transitions don't work, as you can see, it "moves" photos immediately without my transitions, but I need that transitions, or it'll be ugly.

**Fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/0Lg891p0/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="cs-CZ"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta name="generator" content="Rostislav_Danko">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web.css">
        <title>Rostislav Danko</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="web">
            <div id="galerie">
                <div id="fotky">
                    <img id="fotka1" src="fotka1.jpg" alt="fotka1" />
                    <img id="fotka2" src="fotka2.jpg" alt="fotka2" />
                    <img id="fotka3" src="fotka3.jpg" alt="fotka3" />
                </div>
                <div id="arrow_left" class="animace1"></div>
                <div id="arrow_right" class="animace2"></div>
                <script>
                    document.querySelector('.animace1').onclick=function() {
                        var d = document.getElementById("fotka1");
                        d.className = d.className + " fly1";
                        var t = document.getElementById("fotka2");
                        t.className = t.className + " fly1";
                        var t = document.getElementById("fotka3");
                        t.className = t.className + " fly1";
                    }
                </script>
                <script>
                    document.querySelector('.animace2').onclick=function() {
                        var d = document.getElementById("fotka1");
                        d.className = d.className + " fly2";
                        var t = document.getElementById("fotka2");
                        t.className = t.className + " fly2";
                        var t = document.getElementById("fotka3");
                        t.className = t.className + " fly2";
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

CSS

```
#web {
    background-color: #FF0;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1500px;
}
#galerie {

}
#fotky {

}
#fotka1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    border: solid 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka1.fly1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka1.fly2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -300px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    border: solid 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka2.fly1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka2.fly2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -300px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 800px;
    border: solid 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka3.fly1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka3.fly2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -300px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#arrow_left {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-left: 470px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
#arrow_right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-left: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "infinite clicks"?  Function is executed when clicked as many time as clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that you keep adding classes to the elements and never remove the old classes, which is why your click only works once. You need to clear the old class before setting the new one:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('.animace1').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("fotka1").className = "fly1";
        document.getElementById("fotka2").className = "fly1";
        document.getElementById("fotka3").className = "fly1";
    };
    document.querySelector('.animace2').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("fotka1").className = "fly2";
        document.getElementById("fotka2").className = "fly2";
        document.getElementById("fotka3").className = "fly2";
    };
</script>
```

The other initial "sudden jump" problem is that you have conflicting CSS stuff, you can simplify things to just say this:

```
#fotka1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    border: solid 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 8px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#fotka1.fly1 {
    left: 300px;
}
#fotka1.fly2 {
    left: -300px;
}
```

**See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lg891p0/1/**